# Where is the temp folder on Android devices?

Tags: android, temp

Where is the temp folder located on Android phones?

Comment: What do you mean by temp folder, generally Android applications have their own isolated storage provided by the system.  What are you storing in a 'temp' folder?

Comment: It might be good to migrate this question to https://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: @pevik No, because we are talking about file-only temp directories. Something that is used in development.

Comment: @GauravMall but https://android.stackexchange.com/ is IMHO also for development. At least there are similar questions.

Comment: @pevik Well, could be. Anyways I don't agree. That's okay you can have a different opinion on the matter :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reading [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b59af1a9940b87df) from the android developers google group leads me to believe that there is not 1 global temp directory, and each application is expected to maintain their own temporary files.

Comment: Link is dead/spam/banned

Comment: See here: https://www.quora.com/Where-should-I-find-temp-files-in-Android-mobiles

Answer (score 39):

The temporary directory is `/data/local/tmp`.

I've seen some comments that claim you need to be rooted to access it but I'm not sure that's true. Whilst it is true that you need root to freely access `/data`, this is not required for `/data/local/tmp`.

I have verified this on Android 5.1.1.

Comment: Tested on Android 4.x and 7.x and on both it's working fine. It's possible to create subdirectories (using `adb shell`) and store screenshots in that temp directory and then pull them from the device using `adb`. Tested on non-rooted devices.

Comment: How about is the premission? Will it be accessed by any app?

Answer (score 14):

I believe what you're looking for is getCacheDir()!

Comment: cache ≠ tmp, caches are useful to store around, whereas temp files are meant to be deleted.

Comment: Android has the functions File.createTempFile() and File.createTempDirectory(), but they also create files in  Context.getCacheDir()

Comment: And how can i call this function?

Answer (score 2):

The files downloaded using `createTempFile()` are stored in folder:

```
/data/data/YOURapp/cache/
```