# Where is the /tmp in android?

Tags: android, embedded-linux

i'm a developer for driver not app. Recently, i transplant ghostscript to android, it works okay in embedded linux. but it works no okay in Android, because it need /tmp, it can works okay after i create a /tmp. So, my problem is **where is the /tmp in android** or **has other solution in my case** ?

Comment: This post might be helpful to you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364740/where-is-the-temp-folder-in-android-device
Good luck!

Comment: i'm a develper driver not app, i had seen your link. it no help for me.

Comment: If you're a root dev hobbyist making apps only for your own purposes and don't plan on distributing your stuff, you can abuse `/dev` and do `mkdir -p /dev/tmp`. `/dev` is a small ram disk on some distros and therefore cleared on power off. Useful for basic hacking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try /data/local/tmp you can even execute from here. Note that you can access /data/local/tmp on unrooted devices (done it on nexus 10), you cannot access /data. You have to address full path.

Comment: /data/local/tmp very Good but it can be cleanlike PC linux  when reboot ?

Comment: From my exp it does not auto clean, and for me it works as I deploy driver testing tools which want to persist on reboot. You can clean it up yourself though.

Comment: i fond ghostscript will clean "/tmp" by itself, now i just need redirect it. thank you very much!