# What is the Android equivalent of /tmp and how do I get Python scripts to use it?

Tags: android, python, pelican

I am trying to use pelican (python) on Android (in termux). It fails when pelican tries to write to /tmp which near as I can tell, does not exist, and/or is a read-only file system.

The error is from os.py, in makedirs(name, mode)

```
OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/tmp'
```

- How do I tell any sort of script on Android to use a different location for /tmp?
- How do I tell python on Android (in Termux) to use a different location for /tmp?
- What is the Android equivalent of /tmp?

Editing to respond to suggestion this is a duplicate:

I found that answer helpful, but it doesn't pertain to this question.

I tried the instructions suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18280309/608970 and found that by setting TMP, TMPDIR and TEMP that I can indeed change /tmp for python and create tmp files, IF the script uses the tempfile module.

Apparently, pelican does not. Which leaves my original question, in Android what is the model for /tmp, how do we port arbitrary scripts, and does it require a change to the code, or can it be otherwise fixed by changing the Android environment the code works within?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does python tempfile writes its files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280245/where-does-python-tempfile-writes-its-files)

Comment: Thanks @PeterWood, I found that answer helpful, but it doesn't pertain to this question.

I tried the instructions suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18280309/608970 and found that by setting TMP, TMPDIR and TEMP that I can indeed change /tmp for python and create tmp files, IF the script uses the tempfile module.

Apparently, pelican does not. Which leaves my original question, in Android what is the model for /tmp and how do we port arbitrary scripts?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/41105574/493161, it's /data/local/tmp, but my experience with termux is that it cannot read many/most files and directories that can be seen using adb from the desktop, and has write access to nothing (that I've found) outside its own files. I'd suggest `mkdir $HOME/tmp` instead, and using that.

Some of the other answers on that same question have good information on the lack of /tmp. Note that /data/local/tmp does not have the sticky ("t") bit set, nor does it have full read/write access to all users, as does Linux.

Answer (score 0):

A better answer for many use cases is to use the file sharing options built into termux, documented at https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Sharing_Data

```
$ termux-setup-storage
$ cp test.png ~/storage/downloads
$ xdg-open ~/storage/downloads/test.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to preface, I understand that this is an old question and the asker of it might have very well moved on by now (and probably has), but I'll answer it anyway for posterity. I will also use Termux environment variable names to keep the answer simple.

As apps seem to be expected to manage its own temporary files in modern Android versions, Termux uses the TMPDIR environment variable which is set to `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp` by default as of my writing this, and you can use it in Python by simply referencing that entire directory name followed by (another forward slash and) the name of whatever file you need. $TMPDIR is also equivalent to `"$PREFIX/tmp"`.

I'm not going to cover the exact syntax for opening and closing files in Python, but you can verify the path yourself with the shell command `echo $TMPDIR`, assuming the variable has not been reassigned. Although you may want to assign the directory to a variable as a string in Python for shorthand.

While you can use an additional library if you want, accessing the /tmp directory works like any other directory so you can do the usual file manipulation in it as you would otherwise, including creating and altering subdirectories. In fact, the Termux wiki states that it "*Can be freely modified by the user.*" It is a combination of the /tmp and /var/tmp directories in common Linux distributions, while $PREFIX/var in Termux should be used more carefully. (Link below.)

If what you want to do is access files from both Termux and other apps/services:

- Running `termux-setup-storage` while the Termux app has the storage access permission should grant symlink access to your Android user files at `$HOME/storage/shared`, which is equivalent to `$PREFIX/home/storage/shared`. This means you can access your device's Downloads folder, for example, with `/data/data/com.termux/files/home/storage/shared/Downloads` in any application that doesn't expand shell environment variables, like Python. (Your device might have a slightly different file system, this is just what works on the Google Pixel 7. YMMV.)
- You could also run `mkdir "$HOME/storage/shared/[yourdirectory]"`. You can then access the created directory from any other app that has storage permissions.

Hope this helps future readers.

More information here: [Termux file system layout](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/wiki/Termux-file-system-layout)